# Problem with Adobe Premier masks

Tags: premiere, adobe, mask

I have added a text, created a mask and put mask on the text and when I want to move text, mask moves with it, how can I achieve a result, when mask remains and text moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the text layer, so that the animation works in within the composition and then mask the nested composition.